# Having trouble storing multiple values in a uint256

Tags: solidity, storage

In one uint256 I want to store the entire sender's address of 20 bytes and then 12 bytes of a second address.  In this case the example addresses will be the following:

0x9E1C3a90c6EB03F914dF819CA9b3c891DE003301  sender address

0xdFd6b3Fd6E13C3E6AE53d510bFAb5217b5b39FeC  secondary / other address

I send a tx with the setCharacter function below.

```
setCharacter(0xdFd6b3Fd6E13C3E6AE53d510bFAb5217b5b39FeC, 25)
```

Now when I use the getter to retrieve the data I get the following.

```
getCharacter(25)
owner_address -> 0x9E1C3a90c6EB03F914dF819CA9b3c891DE003301
secondpart -> 0
```

The secondpart = 0 is not what I am shooting for.  I want secondpart to be equal to the equiv of 0xAE53d510bFAb5217b5b39FeC (last 12 bytes of 2nd address)  or 0xdFd6b3Fd6E13C3E6AE53d510 (first 12 bytes of the 2nd address).  Any pointers on where I went wrong?  Thank you for any help.

```
contract storagetest8 {

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) inventories;

    function setCharacter(address other_address, uint256 index1) 
        external 
    {
        uint256 _id = uint256(msg.sender);
        _id |= uint96(other_address)<<160;
        inventories[index1] = _id;        
    }


    function getCharacter(uint256 index1) 
        external view
    returns(address owner_address, uint256 secondpart) {
        uint256 _id = inventories[index1];
        owner_address = address(_id);
        secondpart = uint256(uint96(_id>>160));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fix and there's no need for the `uint96` cast since you need to cast again to `uint256`.

```
contract storagetest8 {

    mapping(uint256 => uint256) inventories;

    function setCharacter(address other_address, uint256 index1) 
        external 
    {
        uint256 _id = uint256(msg.sender);
        _id |= uint256(other_address)<<160;  // fix
        inventories[index1] = _id;        
    }


    function getCharacter(uint256 index1) 
        external view
    returns(address owner_address, uint256 secondpart) {
        uint256 _id = inventories[index1];
        owner_address = address(_id);
        secondpart = _id>>160;  // simplified
    }
}
```

Explanation: In the question, the line in `setCharacter` could be fixed to:
`_id |= uint256(uint96(other_address))<<160;`
Need to cast the 96 bit value back to 256 bits before shifting, because left shifting a 96 bit value by 160 bits equals zero.  But may as well keep using 256 bits.

---

When testing in Remix, I had to quote the address `"0xdFd6b3Fd6E13C3E6AE53d510bFAb5217b5b39FeC", 25` when invoking `setCharacter`.

The result is
secondpart 53951738724962035537443790828 which is 0xAE53d510bFAb5217b5b39FeC

Comment: What does `=|` do? @eth

Comment: @alper `|` is bitwise OR.  `a |= b` is shorthand for `a = a|b`.

Answer (score 2):

I have [introduced the notion of Micro slots](https://ethresear.ch/t/micro-slots-researching-how-to-store-multiple-values-in-a-single-uint256-slot/5338/7), whilst this is still in the early stages, it does allow you to store multiple values in a single uint256 slot. I want to compare the gas costs of using Micro slots with that of using Bitwise shifting to determine which one is more efficient. I just have not got around to this as yet.
Here is [a simple example](https://github.com/second-state/micro-slots/blob/master/eleven_separate_slots_per_uint256.sol) of how this would work in a Solidity contract. Obviously the functions which "get" and "set" the Micro slots would need some validation (to avoid underflow & overflow) and perhaps some event logs emitted etc. This is just a prototype which I hope can move forward as a design pattern for the community to use. For this reason I have opened [this Informational EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/08e28dcaeda388fe03d3cb483a30c04bf9f5ef92/EIPS/eip-draft_micro_slots.md).